# Next.js 13 Application Fails to Navigate to Certain Routes After Random Time Interval in Production

Tags: node.js, nginx, next.js13

I'm hosting a **Next.js (v13.5.2)** application alongside Strapi on a DigitalOcean droplet. I have set up Nginx to manage the routing. However, between 5 to 36 hours after starting the application with `npm run build` and `npm run start` (using PM2), the app begins to malfunction.

### Symptoms:

- The main page loads successfully.
- One of the Client-Side Rendered (CSR) pages loads.
- The routes `/specials`, `/giftcards`, and `/contact` fail to work. Clicking on the navigation links to these routes redirects me back to `domain.com` without trying to access the desired page.
- There are no errors outputted by Next.js or Strapi.
- This behavior persists even when I attempt to run without a domain name and bypassing Nginx.

### Environment Details:

- **OS**: Ubuntu 23.04
- **Node.js**: v20.5.0
- **npm**: v10.1.0
- **Next.js**: v13.5.2

In the browser's network tab, when one of the malfunctioning links is clicked, it results in a **304 HTTP response** with a data size of **0B**.

I've provided a link to the entire codebase for better context: [nextjs-website on GitHub](https://github.com/Enxrm/nextjs-website). Please note that the version on GitHub contains some image optimization errors, but I have since fixed them in my local version. However, the routing issue persists even after these fixes.

### What I Tried:

1. I attempted to run the application **without a domain name** and **without using Nginx** to see if they were the source of the problem.
2. I restarted the **Next.js server** several times to observe if the issue would resolve itself after a fresh start.
3. I also checked the console and server logs for any potential errors or warnings related to the routes or any other application features, but found none.
4. As a temporary solution, I had to stop and delete the current PM2 process, then re-run `build` and `start`.

### Expected Outcomes:

- I expected that bypassing the domain and Nginx would possibly resolve the routing issue, leading to the correct loading of the `/specials`, `/giftcards`, and `/contact` routes.
- I also expected to find some errors or warnings in the logs that might give a clue as to why these routes were misbehaving.

### Actual Outcomes:

- Bypassing the domain and Nginx had no effect on the issue; the same routes still failed to load correctly.
- The logs didn't provide any errors or warnings related to the issue.
- Furthermore, instead of the expected behavior of navigating to the intended route, clicking on the links for these routes redirected me back to the root domain (`domain.com`), and in the browser's network tab, it resulted in a **304 HTTP response** with a data size of **0B**.

### Temporary Solution:

The only way I found to temporarily fix the issue is to stop and delete the current PM2 process, followed by re-running `npm run build` and `npm run start`.